# What was the first appearance of the "Shop Around the Corner" romcom plot?

Tags: first-appearance

In [*The Shop Around the Corner* (1940)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0033045/), two characters bicker in person while falling in love anonymously through letters. The plot has been repeated in [*In the Good Old Summertime* (1949)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0041507/?ref_=nm_knf_t3), [*You've Got Mail* (1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0128853/?ref_=nm_knf_t1) and slightly modified in [*Mujhse Fraaandship Karoge* (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2057441/). In other words, it's a pretty popular and successful scenario for a romcom. Did the writers of *The Shop Around the Corner* create the plot or is it taken from another source? I'd be interested in a history in drama as well as cinema.

Comment: Just as an aside, in "You've got Mail", Meg Ryan ran a bookstore called "The Shop Around The Corner".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shop_Around_the_Corner):

> The screenplay was written by Samson Raphaelson based on the 1937
> Hungarian play Parfumerie by Miklós László.

A quick hop over to Miklós László's [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikl%C3%B3s_L%C3%A1szl%C3%B3) shows:

> Most famous of all the plays that became produced as a motion picture
> during this time was Illatszertár, known in English as Parfumerie. It
> had premiered at the Pest Theatre in Budapest in 1937, [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shop_Around_the_Corner) and shortly
> after László came to New York, the play was adapted as a movie script
> by Samson Raphaelson and became the Ernst Lubitsch motion picture The
> Shop Around the Corner (1940), with James Stewart, Frank Morgan, and
> Margaret Sullavan. A few years later it was re-filmed as In the Good
> Old Summertime (1949), a semi-musical showcase for Judy Garland,
> starring Judy Garland, Van Johnson, and S.Z. Sakall.
>
> In 1963, the play
> was produced as a full Broadway musical with book by Joe Masteroff and
> was titled She Loves Me. She Loves Me had music by Sheldon Harnick and
> Jerry Bock (Fiorello!, Fiddler on the Roof, The Apple Tree). She Loves
> Me, is also often referred to as the "Ice Cream Musical" because of a
> signature song and performance by Barbara Cook. She Loves Me was
> revived in 1993 by the Roundabout Theatre Company and ran for 354
> performances.
>
> In 1998, the play was used once again as the inspiration
> for a screenplay, by Nora Ephron, which became the motion picture
> You've Got Mail, with Tom Hanks and Meg Ryan.
>
> In 2001, the
> Laszlo/Raphaelson MGM script was adapted for the stage in France and
> was produced as a straight play La Boutique au Coin de la Rue ("The
> Shop at the Corner of the Street"). This production was a faithful
> adaptation of the MGM movie script The Shop Around the Corner and ran
> for the 2002 season in Paris at the Théâtre Montparnasse winning top
> honors. The production garnered five Moliere Awards, the French
> equivalent of the American Tony Award — for Best New Play, Best
> Adaptation of a Foreign Work, Best Director, Best Set Design, and Best
> Lighting.
>
> In 2009 "Parfumerie" was finally produced for the first time
> in the United States as an English-language play. With a new
> adaptation by the nephew of Miklós László, EP Dowdall, the production
> took the play back to its original roots exploring with equal emphasis
> both the story of the young lovers and the troubled marriage of the
> shop owner Mr. Maraczek. The play premiered as "The Perfume Shop" in
> December 2009 at the Asolo Repertory Theatre in Sarasota, Florida.
> Almost simultaneously, a separate Canadian production, translated,
> adapted (Robins/Pettle) and produced by the Soulpepper Theatre Company
> under a Canadian arts grant also premiered in Toronto.

So it seems that that particular play, **Parfumerie**, was the first example of the "shop around the corner" plot - and it has been successfully recreated many times since in film form.